# Where can I purchase a barbecue (webber) in Split, Croatia?

Tags: shopping, croatia, split

Where can I purchase a barbecue (webber) in Split, Croatia?  Actually...a location on Vis Croatia would be even better, but that's probably not likely.

Answer (score 1):

This [page of Weber dealers in Croatia](http://www.weberstephen.com.hr/Lista-podajnih-mjesta.aspx) includes Lesnina Split (actually located in Dugopolje).  There is no dealer listed in Vis or Komiža.